SQL - conditional join 2 tables
I'm having some issues performing a conditional join on 2 tables and would appreciate some advice.
Customer Table:

Loans Table

I'm running the following SQL:
SELECT Customers.*, Loans.*
FROM Customers
JOIN Loans ON Customers.CustomerID = Loans.CustomerID
and 
Customers.EndDate < Loans.Date
WHERE Loans.Amount > 500;

However, I'm only interested in the FIRST record from the Loans table which matches the condition. In the example attached, that means CustomerID=2, should join with Loan ID=2 only (and not Loan ID=3 or 4)
Perhaps, I can filter out other records at the end of the join, but is there a better way?
Thank you

There is no OutstandingBalance in your loans table.

Hi - please don't use images as no-one can copy your data if they want to try a solution. Use editable text, formatted as tables, to show the source data and the result you want to achieve

What DBSM are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL)? The syntax for this can vary.

just order by loanId limit 1?
